# What am I missing in my Warshall algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to implement Warshall's algorithm to find the transitive closure of an adjacency matrix. This is what I have for the function:

```
public static int[][] warshall(int A[][]){
    int R[][] = A;
    for (int k = 1; k < n; k++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                if ((R[i][j] == 1) || ((R[i][k] == 1) && (R[k][j] == 1))) {
                    A[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        R = A.clone();
    }
    return A;
}
```

I'm using the following adjacency matrix to test:

```
0100
0001
0000
1010
```

Which should result in :

```
1111
1111
0000
1111
```

I'm not getting anywhere close to this. Can anyone readily see what I am missing?

Thanks for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: I don't see any part of this code traversing vertices or edges.  Also, what is `n`?  It's not defined anywhere in that block of code.

Comment: A graph can be represented as a matrix too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with this particular algorithm but in Java and many other languages (most of them actually), you should ALWAYS start your for loops with index at 0 and NOT 1.

Comment: It could be a transliteration of [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), in which the loops do start at 1 and continue to |V|.

Comment: Wow...I cannot believe I even bothered with this question. The book I am using as a reference has the algorithm listed initializing each iterator to 1 and instead of simply checking that, I just assumed that was correct. My apologies for the ignorant question, and thanks for the tip on something I should have tried from the get-go.

Comment: Btw as a suggestion remove n which you should have as `static int n = someNum;` and use A.length or A[0].length instead (since A is square matrix). It is bad practice to use globals in general..